# how to read and write into existing xml file in metro javascript and html

Tags: html, xml, microsoft-metro

i want to Read/Write in Xml File in metro javascript and html5,but i dont know the code and how should i give the directory of my xml file.
please give me help to read or write from my own xml file

Comment: It seems you are asking two questions: 1-How to read/write into file in JavaScript Metro Apps. For this I suggest using this sample
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597
then you may ask how can I parse/construct XML files after I opened them or when I'm trying to write them back

Answer (score 0):

Answer in the following link is pretty much doing everything you want
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a7847959-edcf-4175-b312-9a03746e29b9/create-xml-file-and-write-xml-data
But that's not the only possible way of reading a file of course.